# Jquery Hide img on mouseenter not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

trying to hide the image when the mouse first hovers over the image.  It does not hide as intended.

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(img).on('mouseenter',function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: using jquery 1.7 i believe I am unsure if that could be the cause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change**

```
$(img)
```

**To**

```
$('img')
```

You missed quotes.

or else use `id` or `class`

**For id**

```
$('#image_id')
```

**For class**

```
$('.image_class')
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("img").on("mouseenter",function(){
      $(this).hide();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the `id` attribute set to `img` in your `HTML` code?.

It should be like this,

**HTML**

```
<html>
   <head></head>
    <body>
        <img id="img" src="test.jpg" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**jQuery block**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(img).on('mouseenter',function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

**Working DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/0emvkyb5/

Hope this helps!

Comment: yoru fiddle works for me,  however why in the world does mine not lol?  https://jsfiddle.net/sLtgozfj/1/

Comment: You have failed to include the `jquery` library under the `external sources` of your `fiddle`, I have updated your example, Check out the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sLtgozfj/3/

Answer (score 1):

You need to put img like this 'img'. Otherwise, it'll be understand as a variable.

If you have multiple image in your html page. It's better to put an id in your img tag so you can reference it.

```
<img src="path" id="myImg" />
```

So you can call  `$('#myImg')` instead of `$('img')`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('img').on('mouseenter',function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

Here's a working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dx8z2wtf/).

Comment: I have to be doing something wrong,  my Fiddle isnt working.  https://jsfiddle.net/sLtgozfj/

Comment: @chriscozzens you didn't add jQuery as an external ressource. (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js)

Comment: @chriscozzens you're welcome. It often happens to me too :)